# Recreating Ajax POST

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

I want to recreate Ajax POST which I can peak via Chrome's debugger.

I created post like this:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    data: { "defaults": "default", "culture": "en-US", "skip": 20, "take": 20, "query": "", "filters": [], "fulltext": [], "sorting": { "field": "ModifiedOn", "asc": false } }

})
.done(function (msg) {
  alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
});
```

I'm getting 500 error. I check and my Request Payload looks like this:

```
defaults=default&culture=en-US&skip=20&take=20&query=&sorting%5Bfield%5D=ModifiedOn&sorting%5Basc%5D=false
```

However the source post, which I want to recreate has different Request Payload:

```
{"defaults":"default","culture":"en-US","skip":20,"take":20,"query":"","filters":[],"fulltext":[],"sorting":{"field":"ModifiedOn","asc":false}}
```

I think it is causing the error.

How can I modify my request to make Request Payload look like the latter one?

Comment: `"sorting":{"field":"ModifiedOn","asc":false}` is apparently being parsed as `"sorting":"{field:ModifiedOn,asc:false}"`; do you need to use an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> data: { "defaults": "default", "culture": "en-US", "skip": 20, "take": 20, "query": "", "filters": [], "fulltext": [], "sorting": { "field": "ModifiedOn", "asc": false } }

This line is causing the Error. You need to stringify your Data like so:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ "defaults": "default", "culture": "en-US", "skip": 20, "take": 20, "query": "", "filters": [], "fulltext": [], "sorting": { "field": "ModifiedOn", "asc": false } })
```

Please read the documentation about [jQuery.ajax()-function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). You can check all Parameters with their Type.